# Joomla! - Import users from CSV file

Tags: csv, joomla, import

I am running Joomla! 2.5.1 for my website.

I wish to have this mass-registration function which allows administrators to import users from a CSV file.

I know there's many extensions available for what I've mentioned above.
But I want to be able to add custom fields such as "company name", "position in company", etc.

How can I do this? Is there any FREE extension which can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few components that will allow you to automatically import users from a CSV:

J-Import: http://mycircletree.com/products/joomla-and-jomsocial-user-creation-data-import-component/ 
CSV Import: http://www.reviewsforjoomla.com/csv-import

CSV Improved: http://www.csvimproved.com/

Comment: It mentions the 3 main tables. But what about the table that stores the contact information such as address, country, etc.? And how are the 3 tables linked to the table that stores the contact information?

Comment: users table contains all the address details by default

Comment: Users table only contains id, name, username, email, password, usertype, block, sendEmail, registerDate, lastvisitDate, activation, params.

Comment: my jos_users contains all the address params as well (address,city,country,state,zip) maybe I added it manually a long time ago and I just don't remember :)))

Comment: And i found out that for Joomla 2.5.1, there isn't core_acl_aro and core_acl_groups_aro_map tables.

Comment: May i know which Joomla version are you using?

Comment: I found the tables. But now, may i know how joomla store the password into the users table?

Answer (score 1):

Use "Full Convert Enterprise" software.Trial Version is Free.
You can Convert your database From any format ( Access,Excel,CSV,MYSQL,...) to other format

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at our [Joomla & JomSocial User Import Component](https://mycircletree.com/products/joomla-and-jomsocial-user-creation-data-import-component/). It does exactly what you're looking for: importing users into Joomla 1.5 - 2.5, and imports JomSocial Data as well!

Answer (score -1):

You can use http://elite-effect.ro/elite-xl
i dont know if it works for joomla 2.5..
you can give it a try.

Comment: It says it's only for 3.x.